# Populate docusign company tab

Tags: docusignapi

In docusign, we created a template with two fields: Full Name and Company. For the company field, there is a unique data label id that was filled in. You can see a screenshot below

[Docusign Company Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XumaD.png)

Now, I am using the docusign api to create an envelope, populate the fields, then open a signing console. When I am creating the envelope, I send the following JSON payload to 
`restapi/v2/accounts/UNIQUE ID/envelopes`

```
{
   "emailSubject": "Some Subject",
   "status": "sent",
   "compositeTemplates": [
      {
         "serverTemplates": [
            {
               "sequence": "1",
               "templateId": "SOME ID"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates": [
            {
               "recipients": {
                  "signers": [
                     {
                        "name": "Ashwin Jacob",
                        "email": "admin@ashwinjacob.com",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "clientUserId": "1",
                        "status": "sent",
                        "embeddedRecipientStartURL": "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN",
                        "roleName": "Advisor",
                        "tabs": {
                           "companyTabs": [
                              {
                                 "tabLabel": "Company 33ff014b-79a4-464f-b6c0-c4846861f3df",
                                 "value": "ashwinjacob1"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "carbonCopies": null
               },
               "sequence": "1"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The full name will appear on the docusign console. However, the company name will not appear. As you can see I am using the same datalabel as indicated in the screenshot(sorry it is cut off).

I also noticed that envelope form data has no value. So clearly it is not being sent along, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong in the JSON contract.

[Docusign Form Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBpiA.png)

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here?

**Updates**
I took the suggestion about using text label and I am still getting no luck.

[Text Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL3F8.png)

Here is the new JSON payload

```
{
   "emailSubject": "Some Subject",
   "status": "sent",
   "compositeTemplates": [
      {
         "serverTemplates": [
            {
               "sequence": "1",
               "templateId": "SOME ID"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates": [
            {
               "recipients": {
                  "signers": [
                     {
                        "name": "Ashwin Jacob",
                        "email": "admin@ashwinjacob.com",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "clientUserId": "1",
                        "status": "sent",
                        "embeddedRecipientStartURL": "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN",
                        "roleName": "Advisor",
                        "tabs": {
                           "textTabs": [
                              {
                                 "tabLabel": "Company Label",
                                 "value": "ashwinjacob1"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "carbonCopies": null
               },
               "sequence": "1"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around, if you want to insert your own custom text tab from the API then you need to insert it through the API. You can't edit an existing custom text tab that is on the docusign template.

Answer (score 1):

You `cannot prepopulate` Company Tab from your envelope creation request. DocuSign automatically populates this value if the signer has a DocuSign account and has Company value available in his/her `My Preferences`. As an alternative, if you want to prepopulate some text for Company using API, then you should use a `Text Tab` instead of Company Tab, and make it read only.

Comment: I tried that but still to no luck. You can see my update from above

Comment: In server template also, have you change from Company Tab to TextTab and put the text tab's tablabel as `Company Label`?

Comment: No the labels are part of the inlineTemplates. Are you saying that I need to add the recipients to the server side templates? I am only asking because the api says you can only add sequence and template id

Comment: Also can you please download your server template and send it to me at docusign.sso@gmail.com, I will run it in my account and check the issue.

Comment: Sorry due to security issues, I am unable to send our document

Comment: can you please send me your templateId, I can check what datalabel you have used and are you using it correctly on the envelope API call