# DataLabels Not Shown in Template Creation Console

Tags: javascript

I built an integration with the DocuSign API in the sandbox environment and it is ready to move to production. We purchased the Basic API package this morning only to find that we can't set dataLabels in our template creation page. The attributes pane on the right just doesn't have the dataLabel field on it. I'm here to try to find out why. Without the dataLabel, we can't pre-fill data before sending it for signing as far as I know. I've logged out and logged back in to the admin console. I've confirmed it shows our Basic API package.

P.S. I understand this has nothing to do with actual code. I attempted to get help from a DocuSign live chat rep and he wouldn't give me anything but a canned response to come here and submit a ticket and refused to give me anything else.

Comment: DocuSign directed you to Stackoverflow? That is odd. Are you certain your plan level includes Data Labels? Maybe there are some clues in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379986/populate-docusign-company-tab?

Answer (score 1):

I went through the live chat again with a different rep and we got it sorted out. Turns out they have to send you an email and you have to "enable" that feature through the email or they won't show up.

Comment: this is the silliest thing i have ever heard, and i've been trying to figure out why they dont show up for me